# Unable to send email using System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am currently trying to send an email from a application to my email adress.
Every time when I try to execute the application I get the error:

IOException: No data can be read from the transmission connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

```
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Port = 465;
        smtp.Host = "mail.gmx.com";                 
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        message.From = new MailAddress("something@something.com");
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("test.test@gmx.com"));
        message.Subject = cbx_SubjectEmail.Text;
        message.Body = txt_EmailText.Text;
        smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: I don't know if this is your first problem but you aren't setting any credentials.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I also tried it with them but it didn't work.